# Connecting to lucid chart api

Tags: java, oauth, scribe, lucidchart

I'm trying to use lucid chart api. They are using oAuth1. But when I'm trying to connect, I get the following error :

> **Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'Invalid oauth_verifier'**

```java
package rest;

import org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder;
import org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi;
import org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest;
import org.scribe.model.Response;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
import org.scribe.model.Verb;
import org.scribe.model.Verifier;
import org.scribe.oauth.OAuthService;
import api.LucidApi;

public class RestManager {

    public void create() {

        OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(LucidApi.class)
                .apiKey("302a5264e8eae5e55f03d04c5ea875729fcf37ff")
                .apiSecret("99cdc2c80bd04cdd068b0f9b07a4322fc7254fae")
                .callback("http://localhost:8080/").build();
        System.out.println("ss"+service.getRequestToken().getRawResponse());

        Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
        String authUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
        System.out.println("authurl" + authUrl);

        Verifier v = new Verifier(service.getRequestToken().getRawResponse());
        Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, v);
        System.out.println("raw response-"+accessToken.getRawResponse());
        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://www.lucidchart.com/visio/conversions");
        request.addBodyParameter("reg_level", "free");
        request.addBodyParameter("visio", "@/home/dilshankm/VSD/flowchart.vsd");
        request.addBodyParameter("name", "flowchart.vsd");
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request); // the access token from step                                            // 4
        Response response = request.send();
        System.out.println("response"+response.getBody());
    }
}
```

How can I get the verifier from lucid chart api?

Comment: This question is rather old now. Have you tried this again recently? Is it still not working?